# MongoDB - Why is an int represented as a string?

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm working with a zip code database. The data stored in each document includes city, state, zip #, and coordinates (two numbers). However, the zip # is stored as a string instead of an int. Does anybody know why this may be?

Comment: Are the zips only for the US? Other countries use both numbers and letters.

Answer (score 3):

To allow easy handling of the zip codes that start with 0, without requiring the user to re-format them? You want the ZIP code for Montague, NJ to come out as "07827", not "7827".

Comment: To amplify this fine answer, postcode 07827 is not an integer. Even though it looks like one it is a name for a region just as "Joe Balin" is a name for a person. You can't meaningfully add, multiply or compare postcodes which makes them not integers; it is just a name composed of digits.

Comment: or "C3PO" is the name of a robot.